How to Invoke queue trigger function?
I have created a simple trigger function from a template, this is working perfectly fine if I debug from Visual Studio, which is
once I add message manually to my queue, I can see that message in debug output in my Visual Studio.
So, I plan to publish it to my portal, and now, if I add a message to queue, I do not see any output in the kudu terminal and I do not see any message getting dequeued.
How can the queue trigger function be invoked?
This is my simple code:
[Function(nameof(Function1))]
public string Run([QueueTrigger("sample", Connection = "ConnString")] QueueMessage message)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {message.MessageText}");
    return message.MessageText;
}


And this is the output from app service editor terminal

Sorry if its sound lame, am new to Azure :)
Thanks a ton in advance!

Have you checked in the Function App under Invocations?

Thanks for the detailed steps, in my case, i missed to add ConnString in my environment variables, it started picking files post adding this.

You can directly see the logs in the Invocations of the Function in the Azure Function App.
After deployment, make sure to add the queue connection in the Function app > Environment variables > App settings as shown below,
ConnString": "<storageConneString>


I have sent a message in the Azure storage queue as shown below,

Azure Function App Invocations :
After some time, I got the logs in the Function under Invocations as shown below.

Function1.cs :
using Azure.Storage.Queues.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
 
namespace FunctionApp8
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;
 
        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
 
        [Function(nameof(Function1))]
        public void Run([QueueTrigger("sample", Connection = "ConnString")] QueueMessage message)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {message.MessageText}");
        }
    }
}

local.settings.json :
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "ConnString": "<storageConneString>"
  }
}

